# Double variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

```
#! /bin/bash

source_id="1 2 3 4 5 "
target_id="one two three four five"


for $target_id in ${!source_id[*]}
do
    echo " id " $target_id is " name is "${source_id[$targetid]}
done
```

I want print:

```
name is 1 id is one  
name is 2 id is two
```

and so on…

Comment: You need to read up on bash arrays: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### bash v4+, solution with associative arrays:

If you have bash version greater than 4, this way might be better:

```
target_id=(
    ["1"]="one"
    ["2"]="two"
    ["3"]="three"
    ["4"]="four"
    ["5"]="five"
)

for source_id in ${!target_id[*]}
do
    echo "name is ${target_id["${source_id}"]} id is "${source_id}""
done
```

Here read more about associative arrays in bash:
[Associative arrays in bash](https://linuxhint.com/associative_array_bash/)

### Solution with regular arrays:

```
source_id=(1 2 3 4 5)
target_id=("one" "two" "three" "four" "five")

array_len="${#source_id[@]}"

for (( index = 0 ; index < "${array_len}" ; index++ ))
do
    echo "name is ${target_id[${index}]} id is ${source_id[${index}]}"
done
```

You can read about bash arrays here : [bash arrays](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you intend in this easier way :

```
#!/bin/bash

source_id='
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five'

echo "$source_id" | sed '/^ *$/d' | while read id name
do
    echo "id is $id and name is $name"
done
```

If for some reason you NEED to use arrays, this is the right syntax for it :

```
#!/bin/bash

source_id=(1 2 3 4 5)
target_id=(one two three four five)

for (( i=0; i < "${#source_id[@]}" ; i++))
do
    echo "id is ${source_id[$i]} and name is  ${target_id[$i]} " 
done
```